# Is there an easy way to cast between two List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, generics

```
var candidates = (from l in db.GetLeads(lat, lon, role, radius + 10)
                  orderby l.Distance
                  select l);
        return (List<CandidateResult>)candidates;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your "candidates" variable isn't a `List<T>` - it's an `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T`.

However, `List<T>` isn't variant in `T` even in C# 4 (as it's a class, and classes are invariant; and also because it uses `T` in both an input and an output position).

Your simplest solution is to get the right type of sequence to start with and then call `ToList`:

```
var candidates = (from l in db.GetLeads(lat, lon, role, radius + 10)
                  orderby l.Distance
                  select (CandidateResult) l);
return candidates.ToList();
```

You can call `Cast` instead if you want, as shown below but in this particular case I don't think it makes it any nicer.

```
var candidates = (from l in db.GetLeads(lat, lon, role, radius + 10)
                  orderby l.Distance
                  select l);
return candidates.Cast<CandidateResult>()
                 .ToList();
```

Note that when you're only really doing one thing (ordering in this case) it's often simpler not to use query expressions, e.g.

```
return db.GetLeads(lat, lon, role, radius + 10)
         .OrderBy(l => l.Distance)
         .Cast<CandidateResult>()
         .ToList();
```

Comment: Tried the first one and got a "Cannot convert type'x.x.GetLeadsResult' to 'x.x.CandidateResult'.  Does this mean that my types are not compatible, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it means your types aren't compatible. What are the two types like, and how do you want to convert between them?

Comment: One type is the result of a UDF in SQL.  I'm using linq to get the result, but I need to pass it from my repository back to the controller (MVC).  So I added a type to my Model with the same properties / types.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't convert from one type to another just because they've got the same properties. I suggest you add a constructor to create a `CandidateResult` from a `GetLeadsResult`.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the Cast extension method, i.e.:

```
return candidates.Cast<CandidateResult>();
```

Comment: I'm getting a message that says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<CandidateResult>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CandidateResult>'.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var candidates = (from l in db.GetLeads(lat, lon, role, radius + 10)
                  orderby l.Distance
                  select l).ToList();
```